Why don't I see the biology community in the list of all my communities when I am on another one ? Please help?
I have been a member of Stackexchange for quite a few years already. One by one, I joined five communities (not counting "metas"). Just the day before yesterday I joined a sixth one, namely biology. When I am here (whether "regular" or "meta") I can see the five others in the list of my communities. But when I am on the other ones, I do not see Biology.
Can this be fixed ? Thanks !

My guess would be that this depends on an automatic process which runs only once a day or so. Wait at least for another 24 hours before contacting anybody on this topic. This can only be fixed (if it is needed at all) by stackexchange, not by the mods here at biology.

OK, I'll wait awhile. But how can I contact "higher authorities" at stackexchange if it does not fix by itself ?

If you mean in the upper right, I think only 5 communities are listed there. You can use the "edit" link to choose which 5.
If you have tech support issues that can't be solved by talking to other users (e.g., posting on Meta) there is a Contact link at the bottom of every page to reach company staff.

The maximum is 5 ! I understand. So I can remove each of the others  from its own  page and choose biology instead !

Hmmm The five up there are the same whatever page on is on. OK, I'll manage...

@Alfred I take it back, you should be able to add more than 5.
